# Herencia de atributos

Tags: php, herencia

¿Cómo seria posible acceder al atributo $foo en el siguiente ejemplo de herencia? Pensaba que mediante la herencia se podía acceder a propiedades y metodos de la clase padre pero en este ejemplo me da error.

```
<?php
    class ClasePadre {
        $foo= 5;
    }

    class ClaseHija extends ClasePadre {

        public function miFuncion(){

          echo $foo;  
        }
    }

    $nueva=new ClaseHija();
    $nueva->miFuncion();
```

Answer (score 0):

Cuando declaras una variable o metodo en una clases debe indicar la visibilidad de las variables o metodo; y para verlo en la clase hijas tienes que usar el $this

```
class ClasePadre {
        protected $foo = 5;
        }
    class ClaseHija extends ClasePadre {

            public function miFuncion(){

              echo $this->foo;  
            }
        }

    $nueva=new ClaseHija();
    $nueva->miFuncion();
```

Answer (score -1):

Debes llamar a $foo en el contexto correcto.

```
 echo $this->foo
```

Además, tienes que añadir el ámbito a la variable $foo

`protected $foo= 5;`

Comment: Lo he probado y no funciona. 
El error es:
FATAL ERROR syntax error, unexpected '$foo' (T_VARIABLE), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) on line number 3( que es las linea que tiene $foo=5)

Comment: Añade el ámbito a la variable $foo en la clase padre. "protected $foo= 5;"

Comment: Ahora si, gracias!